# Jquery post a form and preview

Tags: jquery, forms

I am writing a page that has a form with 2 text fields. There is a save button, that will save the content.
Now, I want to create a preview button that will submit the data to another handler and format it and return the formatted version in a new windows.

How I can archive this?

Comment: What it does after save ?

Comment: How your preview looks like ?

Comment: Have you tried using `$.post()`?

Comment: it would be a html editor. So all the content will be html content. So the preview will be html preview plus some my custom template content

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with an `ajax` call.

While clicking on `preview` button call an ajax function and sent all the parameters it required to `server side scripting`.

Create `HTML in sever side` and return as `JSON` or just `print it in text format`.

After receiving,  in success function, you can have a pop-up, and paste the response contents to that pop-up.

Use `Jquery Pop-up` tools for this.

http://collegegfx.com/10-best-jquery-popup-plugins/

http://smashingspy.com/32-best-jquery-popup-window-dialog-box-example/